# Container does not start in Azure or deployment is prevented due to compatibility issue

Tags: iis, azure, docker, asp-classic

I am successful in containerizing the demo classic asp in local environment and it works - but in deploying to Azure I encounter (for example with the following base images "mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-1803, mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis") always either the error:

"The parameter WindowsFxVersion has an invalid value. Cannot run the specified image as a Windows Containers Web App. App Service supports Windows Containers up to Windows Server Core 2019 and Nanoserver 1809. Platform of the specified image: windows, Version: 10.0.18362.658;"

... OR ...

with the other base images (microsoft/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2016) I get the following error when I browse in the web-browser to successfully the deployed container:

"The Web App's container could not start"

and then I can see in the log-data of Azure portal's container settings the following error: ... ERROR - Site: asp-sixeyed - Unable to start container. Error message: Modify Compute System failed. ...

Here is my Dockerfile for the :

```
# escape=`
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-1803

SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]

RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-ASP; `

EXPOSE 80

RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'; `
    md c:\mywebsite; `
    New-IISSite -Name "mywebsite" `
                -PhysicalPath 'c:\mywebsite' `
                -BindingInformation "*:80:";

ADD . c:\mywebsite
```

I have a repository in Azure where the uploaded container is downloaded, and configured as part of the container based web app.

I have found some links (https://docs.microsoft.com/answers/questions/8381/azure-app-service-using-a-windows-container-failin.html, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t, https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images) where the similar issues are reported and something about the cause is also said but - still I cannot figure out how to solve this.

And here is the nice and clear demo of the containerization of classic asp: https://olikka.com.au/news-items/containerize-and-migrate-legacy-classic-asp-to-azure-app-service, but I cannot make it work because of the issues reported above.

I am just beginner with docker and this has taken from me 2-3 days and no success. Could any docker / iis / Azure expert give some guidance how to solve this impasse?

Comment: This is possibly because of Microsoft's recent platform Upgrades. I have updated the original source code that you mentioned and it should now work on azure web apps now !

Comment: Yes, Imran, the image (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis:windowsservercore-ltsc2019) you provided really worked and now container really started up finally after wasting time with the trials of approximately a dozen of false base images. So thank you very,very much!  - I also faced locally an other issue with lines "RUN Invoke-WebRequest ... Error msg: "Invoke-WebRequest : The remote name could not be resolved:
'download.microsoft.com'
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/E/C9E81 ...". Any idea what is the cause of this issue?